# How to get results of more than one condition at a time

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I even don't know how to ask my question!

I have a variable like this:

```
$value['state 1'] = true;
$value['state 2'] = false;
$value['state 3'] = false;
$value['state 4'] = true;
```

I want to keep some strings about every state that has `false` value by conditions or something else and if all of states have `true` value, have another strings, for example:

```
$message = "";
if ($value['state 1'] !== true){
     $message .= "State one isn't working!\n";
} elseif ($value['state 2'] !== true){
     $message .= "State two isn't working!\n";
} elseif ($value['state 3'] !== true){
     $message .= "State three isn't working!\n";
} elseif ($value['state 4'] !== true){
     $message .= "State four isn't working!\n";
} else {
$message = "All states works!";
}
```

In this code, after the first true condition other conditions doesn't be checked, so I used `switch case` at this way:

```
switch (false){
     case $value['state 1']:
        $message .= "State one isn't working!\n";
     case $value['state 2']:
        $message .= "State two isn't working!\n";
     case $value['state 3']:
        $message .= "State three isn't working!\n";
     case $value['state 4']:
        $message .= "State four isn't working!\n";
        break;
     default:
        $message = "All states works!";
        break;
}
```

In this code after matching the first case, all strings after that case will be added to $message variable!

Well, I think now you know what I wanna do! can you help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate them and at the end check your `$message` variable:

```
$message = "";
if ($value['state 1'] !== true){
     $message .= "State one isn't working!\n";
}
if ($value['state 2'] !== true){
     $message .= "State two isn't working!\n";
}
if ($value['state 3'] !== true){
     $message .= "State three isn't working!\n";
}
if ($value['state 4'] !== true){
     $message .= "State four isn't working!\n";
}
if (!$message) {
$message = "All states works!";
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works well as I knew, I thought is there any other ways but using separate if statement.

Answer (score 3):

You should really use a loop, to allow for easy expansion of conditions in the future:

```
<?php
$value['state 1'] = true;
$value['state 2'] = false;
$value['state 3'] = false;
$value['state 4'] = true;

$message = null;
foreach($value as $key => $state) {
    if($state !== true) {
        $message .= $key . " isn't working!\n";
    }
}
echo $message ?? 'all states working'; // null-coalescing (PHP 7+)

//If your php version is older you can echo the message using a regular ternary expression:
print $message ? $message : 'all states working';
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/Fc3G5)

Comment: It is to be noted that `?? ''` is exclusive (ternary) to PHP 7+

Comment: I can't use loop for this, because the states have theirs own names in my main code and I want give them detailed strings, I used numbers here just for have short titles.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check all array indices, you can use something like this

```php
if ($value['state 1'] !== true){
     $message .= "State one isn't working!\n";
} 

if ($value['state 2'] !== true){
     $message .= "State two isn't working!\n";
} 

if ($value['state 3'] !== true){
     $message .= "State three isn't working!\n";
} 

if ($value['state 4'] !== true){
     $message .= "State four isn't working!\n";
} 

if (!$message) {
    $message = "All states works!";
}
```

Or, if you change your array, you can use a loop and you will not need to write the 100500 of `if (...)`

Is loop realisation:

```php
$value = [
    'state_1' => [
        'is_work' => false,
        'error_text' => "State 1 isn't working!\n"
    ],
    'state_2' => [
        'is_work' => true,
        'error_text' => "State 2 isn't working!\n"
    ],
    'state_3' => [
        'is_work' => true,
        'error_text' => "State 3 isn't working!\n"
    ]
];

$message = "";

foreach ($value as $arr) {
    if ($arr['is_work'] !== true) {
        $message .= $arr['error_text'];
    }
}

if ("" === $message){
    $message = "All states works!";
}

echo $message;
```

Output: 

`State 1 isn't working!`

Comment: `$arr['is_work'] === true` gives you an error message and `("" === $message)` the same as `(!$message)`. You're failed

Comment: thanks for giving your time to me, I used this code before, I was thinking about not using separate if statements, and about loop I have to say I can't use loop because I want to give each state a detailed string, not just numbers like these codes here.

Comment: @MohammadHoodaji The error string, in this implementation, can be stored along with the state. I changed to make it clearer

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc63e4cd948bcd43df2d1b850c1f7127146cd384

Comment: @aksen _You're failed_ is a bit harsh, don't you think? Keep up the good work :-)

Comment: @jibsteroos, I don't agree to encourage answers with inbuilt issues.

Comment: @AlexeyBril Yes, it seems nice, thanks for your help